# Android Notifications + C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I've got two classes, Main and C2DMReceiver -- I want the receiver to obviously receive push notifications from C2DM, but I need context in order to push task bar notifications to the UI -- context which is only found in classes extending Activity. Since the notifications are invoking the C2DM receiver class, I can't just instantiate it and pass it context -- how can I notify the user upon the receipt of a C2DM message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C2DMReceiver should extend [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), which will receive a Context through [onReceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29).

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/)